# Adding column to table returns error saying error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When I run this code:

```
$addUniverseColumn = $db->prepare("ALTER TABLE spaceships ADD :universe int");
$addUniverseColumn->bindParam(":universe", $name);
$addUniverseColumn->execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''asfa' int' at line 1' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\php\locationconfig.php:63 Stack trace: #0 D:\XAMPP\htdocs\php\locationconfig.php(63): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\php\locationconfig.php on line 63
```

Note: `$addUniverseColumn->execute();` is the line 63.

I have little to no idea as to what the problem is. I've searched for an answer to the problem but I can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: are you sure $name is set?

Comment: Looks like `bindParam` is quoting the *string* and so produces an invalid DML statement as the column name must be unquoted

Comment: You cannot use a PDO placeholder in an `ALTER TABLE` statement. You can see that the value `asfa` is being quoted as a string, which is what would happen if it was placed in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I would question why you need to perform `ALTER TABLE` statements in your application code. This kind of implies that you might need to be inserting to a different normalized table instead of adding columns to an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders can only work for VALUES, never field/table names. You cannot use a placeholder for the field name in an ALTER query. You'll have to use good old string interpolation for it:

```
$db->prepare("ALTER TABLE spaceships ADD $name int");
```

Comment: What is the value of `$name`? Your error message seems to hint that there's a `'` quote in it: `'asfa`.

Comment: Well it appears to work now. Previously I was adding in a Universe called Universe 1, with a space. Is there any way to allow there to be a space as the column name through this? Am I missing something? Thank you again.

Comment: generally speaking, you shouldn't use spaces in column names. it's not forbidden, but it means you have to remember to quote the field name everywhere you use it, which gets to be tedious. `field_name` is perferable to `field name`. If you INSIST on spaces, then ``ALTER TABLE foo ADD `field name` int`` - note the backticks quoting the field name.